# Energy in $RC$ Circuit

Tags: electric-circuits, energy-conservation, electrical-resistance, capacitance

[image]

In circuit A, the total energy dissipated in the resistor is $\frac{Q_i^2}{2C}$ which equals the initial energy, meaning that **all** the energy was dissipated in the resistor, and lost as heat.

Here's my problem: I have read that in the circuit in figure B, the energy is dissipated as electromagnetic waves (which I have yet to learn about).

Why do these waves not occur in circuit A?

Comment: Read the paper [A Capacitor Paradox](https://puhep1.princeton.edu//~kirkmcd/examples/twocaps.pdf) and all will be explained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Circuit $B$ is an [LC circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LC_circuit) so it will oscillate with an angular frequency $\omega = 1/\sqrt{LC}$. You will probably point out that there is no inductor in the circuit but all electrical components, even a straight wire, have an inductance so your circuit will have an inductance even though it's probably very small. The oscillating current generates an oscillating electromagnetic field around the circuit, and that oscillating EM field radiates energy as EM waves. This is basically how a radio aerial works.

Circuit $A$ is an [RLC circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RLC_circuit) i.e. an LC circuit like $B$ but with a resistor that provides damping. And since the inductance is very small for any reasonable value of the resistance the circuit will be overdamped. That means instead of oscillating the current will decay exponentially with time. Since there are no oscillations there is no oscillating EM field and therefore no EM radiation. All the energy is lost in the resistor instead.

Answer (score 2):

It's because to  generate radiating waves the fields  have to change *rapidly*. In the usual circuits with resistors capaciors and inductors, we assume that the frequencies are low enough that we can make the low frequency or [quasi-static approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasistatic_approximation#Electromagnetism) in which we ignore second derivatives of time in Maxwell's equations.  The resistor is assumed to make the discharge time long enough to ignore radiation. In its absence the capacitor   tries to discharge rapidly  and we need to keep all the terms in Maxwell.

An equivalent way to think about the low-frequency approximation is that we ignore the displacement current term in Ampere's law.